# What kind of fish is this?

Tags: species-identification, ichthyology, freshwater-biology

[image]

What sort of fish is the big one in this picture? I saw it in an aquarium so I don't really know anything about its habitat.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Its a Giant Gourami, *Osphronemus goramy*.

The [giant gourami](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giant_gourami) (Osphronemus goramy) is a freshwater species  believed to be native to [Southeast Asia](http://maps.iucnredlist.org/map.html?id=180720), and has been introduced to other parts  of the world.

This species is commercially important as a food fish and an aquarium fish.

[image]

<sub>(Source: [tropical-fish-keeping](http://www.tropical-fish-keeping.com/tag/giant-gourami#sthash.isQLZk1E.HlKFxkg4.dpbs))</sub>

Reference: fishbase

Comment: Several smaller gouramis' are common in the aquarium trade ; this one maybe only as a special order. Interestingly one of the small ones is also called "giant" (about 4 in. long).